# How did Jesus appear to his disciples after resurrection?

Tags: jesus, resurrection

If we look at

> Luke 24:39 Look at my hands and my feet. It is I myself! Touch me and see; **a ghost does not have flesh and bones, as you see I have**.

So clearly, Jesus was in his **flesh body**. But

> John 20:19 On the evening of that first day of the week, when the disciples were together, **with the doors locked** for fear of the Jewish leaders, Jesus came and stood among them and said, "Peace be with you!"

and also

> John 20:26 A week later his disciples were in the house again, and Thomas was with them. **Though the doors were locked**, Jesus came and stood among them and said, "Peace be with you!"

Both specifically mentioned **the doors were locked**. If Jesus was in flesh form, how did he walk through locked doors to get in? Can we deduce that Jesus used Teleportation? As seen in

> Luke 24:31 Then their eyes were opened and they recognised him, and **he disappeared from their sight**.

Or was it Jesus was with the disciples in the same house already, disguised as someone else, like Jesus used Shapeshifting, as seen in

> Mark 16:12 Afterward Jesus appeared in **a different form** to two of them while they were walking in the country.

If Jesus really has the ability to teleport, then it makes sense that the linen and the cloth were still wrapped and not damaged:

> John 20:6 Then Simon Peter came along behind him and went straight into the tomb. He saw **the strips of linen lying there**, 7 as well as the cloth that had been wrapped around Jesus’ head. **The cloth was still lying in its place**, separate from the linen.

But then there is no point to move the tomb entrance stone to come out...So the main question here is: based on how it was described, can we deduce what ability Jesus used to appear to his disciples?

Comment: Notice that in John 20:17, Jesus said "_Touch me not; for I am not yet ascended to my Father_", but later he _did_ allow people to touch him (e.g. he told Thomas "_reach hither thy hand, and thrust it into my side_").  Obviously Jesus had ascended to heaven (symbolized by the wave-sheaf offering to God on Sunday following Passover) between those events.  Perhaps before his ascension, Jesus was in a fully physical body, needing the rock to be moved, but after ascension he was a fully spiritual being, capable of physical materialization.

Comment: @RayButterworth 'Touch me not' was said to a woman.

Comment: @NigelJ, but he explainded it as "_for I am not yet ascended_", not as "_for you are a woman_".  He had no complaints earlier about being touched by a woman that anointed his feet (Luke 7:46).

Comment: @RayButterworth She used her hair. She did not touch him.

Comment: @NigelJ, "_Then took Mary a pound of ointment of spikenard, very costly, and anointed the feet of Jesus, and wiped his feet with her hair_" sounds like she anointed him first and _then_ finished by wiping off the excess.  But I think your point is that Jesus never allowed women to touch him.  Is there an SE answer for this elsewhere?

Comment: @RayButterworth 'Anointing' involves pouring. One does not require to touch the person.

Comment: Thanks @RayButterworth. But some version explained "_Touch me not_" means "_Do not hold me down_", as in let go of Jesus for he needs to go see his Father. So kind of not related to my question in that context.

Comment: The stone was not removed so that Jesus could get out; it was removed so the disciples could see that he was already gone.

Answer (score 1):

Jesus had a different body: a glorified body.

Which is why he wasn't recognized by Mary:

> When she had said this, she turned around and saw Jesus standing there, **and did not know that it was Jesus.** John 20:11

And why Cleopas and his friends didn't recognize Him either:

> After this, **Jesus appeared in a different form to two of them** as they walked along in the country. Mark 16:12

And has been mentioned oft, Jesus could pass through walls.

At the resurrection of the dead, we will have these bodies too.

> But our citizenship is in heaven, and we eagerly await a Savior from there, the Lord Jesus Christ, who, by the power that enables Him to subject all things to Himself, **will transform our lowly bodies to be like His glorious body.** Philippians 3:20-21

Answer (score 0):

The short, simple, TL;DR response is:  it was a miracle.

Both after **and before** the Resurrection, Jesus (being "the Word," aka "the Son of God") had the ability to work miracles.  Any miracle is, by definition, a temporary suspension of some normally-fixed law of physics, biology, or some other scientific principle.

Take one of the most well-known instances, walking on water:

> 22 Immediately Jesus made the disciples get into the boat and go on
>   ahead of him to the other side, while he dismissed the crowd. 23 After
>   he had dismissed them, he went up on a mountainside by himself to
>   pray. Later that night, he was there alone, 24 and the boat was
>   already a considerable distance from land, buffeted by the waves
>   because the wind was against it.  25 Shortly before dawn Jesus went
>   out to them, walking on the lake. 26 When the disciples saw him
>   walking on the lake, they were terrified. “It’s a ghost,” they said,
>   and cried out in fear. 27 But Jesus immediately said to them: “Take
>   courage! It is I. Don’t be afraid.”  Matthew 14:22-27

For a human being to walk on the surface of water without sinking is no less, and no more, remarkable than a human being passing through a solid barrier such as a locked door.  Both are things that would normally be impossible; the fact that Jesus could do them were *signs,* visible proofs of His divinity.

To say that He used "teleportation" (or any other science-fictionish term) is, IMO, to confuse the whole point of these events.  The bottom line here, the whole point being communicated, is that this was the incarnation of the Omnipotent Creator of the Universe.  As such He had the ability to suspend, alter, and shape physical reality in any way He chose, to accomplish His purposes -- doing so with no more difficulty than a potter shaping a piece of clay.

You bring up a good point at the end, regarding the stone being rolled away -- strictly speaking it wasn't necessary to move it for Him to leave the tomb.  But the rolled-aside stone was a much more powerful and visible statement.  If you will, it was better "advertising" of the Resurrection... a more obvious *sign.*

Comment: Thank you for teaching me more! My take away is biblical study tends to shy away from drilling deeper to investigate more but to take on the face value only. To me, consistency is the key in believing anything. If teleportation wasn't one of the abilities Jesus possesses (e.g. my question above, he may only knows shapeshifting), then stone rolling was a must; otherwise, it was unnecessary and was "staged". Of course, "staging" it could be good (as you said a stronger sign) and bad (e.g. I can say it disproves he knows teleportation) at the same time. May God do things to disprove himself?

Comment: I agree fully, consistency is key. So not trying to be a jerk, but your takeaway is not consistent -- it ignores the whole point of my response. Again, this was the incarnation of the Omnipotent Creator of the Universe. The biblical Jesus was the same being who brought the entire universe into existence from nothing, simply by commanding it all to happen. When talking of such a being, it is not consistent at all to think "He doesn't know teleportation, that's why the stone had to be moved." The conclusion you're drawing is not consistent with the premise.

Comment: Well, in the OT, God suddenly turned into a fleshly man that straight up had lunch with Abraham in Genesis 18:1-8. Most of His miracles, with some major exceptions, seem pretty low-level for Himself and His angels but again it fits His character. He knows and empathises with our weaknesses and fears and takes the plight of the poor, outcast and needy with high concern.

Comment: @GoldExperience A better question is in what sort of body was Jesus resurrected?   After 3 days it would have been decomposed.    So it cannot be the same body.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JDM-GBG for the most part and would only add and thus simplify the question.  After the Resurrection Jesus was God again or of the Godhead and so anything goes. Now, as to the stone I've thought on this and just like the Woman/Women who were first to the tomb as eyewitnesses. It is my opinion that this is another tension used to purify believer. After all who would believe woman or the idea of God moving a stone it seems a bit absurd which I think often is the point. It's all just to remind us that God is God especially when it comes to these varies tensions in the Bible.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Of course I understand that all those abilities are God's power. I was curious to know _how_ or _in what way_ Jesus appeared. Regarding the stone rolling, I beg to differ. A sealed chamber is always more intriguing than an opened tomb (similar to the locked-room mystery in detective stories). If the stone was rolled by the guards in front of the women only to find out Jesus wasn't there already, that would have a much more impact to me, if not all the bible readers/believers.

Comment: @GoldExperience, you're assuming the guards would consent to remove the stone for the women. But the tomb had been sealed and put under guard specifically because the authorities assumed or feared that Jesus' disciples would show up and try to steal the body (read Matthew 27:62:66). If the tomb were still closed when the women showed up, the guards would have just turned them away. Read on though to Matthew 28:1-7, and you can see how the angel's arrival eliminated both problems (stone & guards), letting the women access the tomb.